# Insertion sort of a file

Tags: java

I have the below insertion sort function below, previously I was working with strictly an integer array and called the function below as a means of sorting it. Now in the below function, what I want to do is sort this function based on a file of arbitrary data. AM not entirely sure how to approach this. I tried writing the function and including the file path within the function but am guessing that is not entirely correct. Any suggestions on how to approach this correctly?

```
public static void InsertionSort(int filename[], int size) {
    int index, count;
int temp;
index = 1;
Scanner sca = null;
try {
    sca = new Scanner(new File(
            "C:/Users/Frank/Downloads/wb1913_samp1040.txt"));
    while (sca.hasNextLine()) {
        while (index < size) {
            temp = filename[index];
            count = index;
            while (count >= 0 && temp <= filename[count - 1]) {
                filename[count] = filename[count - 1];
                --count;
            }
            filename[count] = temp;
            index++;
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {

} finally {
    sca.close();

}
```

Updated Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    String file = "C:/Users/jdavis/Downloads/wb1913_samp1040.txt";
    int count;
    Word word = new Word();
    LinkedList WordList = new LinkedList();

    String[] f = {file};


    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File(
                "C:/Users/jdavis/Downloads/wb1913_samp1040.txt"));
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] Word = scanner.nextLine().split("\t");
            word.setWord(Word[0]);
            word.setPartsofSpeech(Word[1]);
            word.setDefinition(Word[2]);
            WordList.InsertAtBack(word);
            WordList.Display();
            System.out.println("Before sorting: " +Arrays.toString(f));
            //sort array
            InsertionSort(f);
            System.out.println("After sorting: ");
            printArray(f);

}


    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {

    } finally {
    //  scanner.close();
    }
    count = WordList.CountList();
    System.out.println(count);

}

public static void InsertionSort(Comparable[] array) {
    Comparable temp;
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
         temp = array[i];
         int j = 0;
         for(j = i; j > 0; j--)
              if(temp.compareTo(array[j - 1]) < 0)
                   array[j] = array[j - 1];
              else
                  break;
         array[j] = temp;
            }

        }

public static void printArray(String[] f){

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f));

}


}
```

Comment: when you said **file of arbitrary data** did you mean all data in file are of same type but can be other than integer ?

Comment: all data within the file are string data

Comment: why not build an array outside of the function from the file and pass it to the function as you did previously. your function would then work generally and not in one specific case and you would not mix sorting with reading

Comment: will it always be string or can be other data type too ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the file path outside of your method? meaning within your main. I would think the insertion sort wouldn't contain the file path

Comment: so in short you want to sort your files based upon words as it is in dictionary..right ???

Comment: @Abhinav yes that is the idea

Comment: @Jevon I tried that but it is not working as I thought it would

Comment: split your approach..
1.write a method which would do string comparison and returns which one comes before..like bat comes before cat..so it should return bat
2. insertion sort's basic assumption is the left array is always sorted. and the new element from right is inserted at correct position..so following this approach you might need a temporary storage like stringbuilder and store the sorted string representation of the file in it and once complete content is sorted and concatenated in stringbuilder write it to a new file..

Comment: i can give you code ...but IMHO you should try it yourself..post what you did and then come back with the stuff that was not working..

Comment: @Abhinav ok I will give it a go

Comment: @AdamNewman string.split() can be a useful thing in ur scenario.read each line as a string and in split give "space" as delimiter..it will return a string array of all words present in the line that you might have read..

Comment: It's very confusing to have a variable called `filename` that is an array of `int` !?!?!

Comment: @Abhinav I made some head way but the problem is getting the actual contents of the file to be read in. I updated my initial post

Comment: `Word word = new Word();
 LinkedList WordList = new LinkedList();
 String[] f = {file};` these are not needed..also String[] f assignment just assigns the string(file path) as one of the value in that string array.Which you don't need

Comment: @Abhinav the linked list and "Word" was to do with another set of classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static boolean doesKeyStringOccursEarlyInDict(String string,String key){
    int i = Math.min(string.length(), key.length());
    int j = 0;
    while(j<i){
        if(string.charAt(j) > key.charAt(j)){
            return true;
        }
        j++;
    }
    //else return false as either both were equal or key does not come early in dictionary
    return false;
}

public static void insertionSort(String[] s){
    for(int i=1;i<s.length;i++){
        String key = s[i];
        int j = i-1;
        while(j>=0 && doesKeyStringOccursEarlyInDict(s[j], key)){
            s[j+1] = s[j];
            j--;
        }
        s[j+1]=key;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //read the file each line
    //split it and store it in an arraylist of string as it can grow..repeat it till u have read all the content 
 ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
    //get the complete string array
    String[] stringarr = (String[]) s.toArray();
    //example : String[] stringarr = {"def","xyz","abc","aaa"};
    insertionSort(stringarr);
    for(String words:stringarr)
    System.out.println(words);
}
```

Above I have given the part that you are looking for.You are already able to read file.So just fill in the blanks in the above code.
Also I was not trying to challenge you rather was encouraging to think first then ask.
After incorporating the above I would encourage you to follow the approach mentioned by Slim and Nishanth.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the below sort method after you get your String

```
public static String[] dictionaryFormString(String[] s)
{
    //
    // Sort each individual string element by alphabetical order
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {
        String wordSt = s[i];
        if(wordSt == null) continue;

        char[] word = wordSt.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(word);
        s[i] = new String(word);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming here that you are challenging yourself (or someone has challenged you) to write an insertion sort of your own, and that you want to insert each element as you read it from a file.

If you just want to read a file and end up with a sorted array, it would be simpler and more efficient to just slurp it into the array out-of-order, then use `Arrays.sort()`. Except as a learning exercise, programmers very seldom write sort algorithms nowadays.

---

You can make your programs much easier to understand by breaking them into more methods - each method does less, and so is easier to understand, but put together they are powerful.

So:

```
private void readIntoSortedArray(Scanner sca, String[] array) {
    while (sca.hasNextLine()) {
        insertInto(array, sca.nextLine());
    }
}

private void insertInto(String[] array, String line) {
    int index = findFirstElementGreaterThan(line);
    shiftElementsByOne(array, index);
    array[index] = line;
}
```

... and so on. Here I've given you the "middle" of your chain of methods. You will need to write a method higher in the stack, that prepares a `Scanner` and calls `readIntoSortedArray`. And you will need to write the methods called by `insertInto()`. Maybe those will call yet more methods.

This also means that you can write small programs to drive these sub-methods and check that they work as you expect, in isolation.

```
 String[] testArray = new String[]{"Adam", "Brian", "Dave"};
 int index = findFirstElementGreaterThan("Clive");
 if(index != 2) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Index should be 2 - was " + index);
 }
```

This is a short step away from *test-driven development*, which is a good thing to adopt early in your studies, because it makes things much easier. (*JUnit* is a very popular tool that does essentially the same thing, nicer).

If, once you've done this, you feel your program has too many tiny methods, you can always "inline" your sub-methods -- but many feel that the right size for a method is *absolutely tiny*.

I guess you want an alphabetical sort. You can't compare strings with `<` and `>` -- you can use `string1.compareTo(string2)` (there are other, more flexible ways, but this is OK for now).

Answer (score 1):

If you have file that contains string and you want to sort it.
One approach could be to create a string array after reading file (assuming it isn't very big file) and then apply sorting.

```
// Read from file
String[] words = someFunctionThatReadFileAndReturnArrayOfString(file);

Arrays.sort(words); // or your sorting function

for (String word : words)
{
   System.out.println(word);
}
```

If you want your `insertionSort` function to be more generic so that it will be independent of data type then you can ask for `Comparable` object from user as a additional parameter to your function and use it to compare objects in your code.

your method signature would be something like this-

```
public static void InsertionSort(Object list[],Comparator<Object> compare)
```

Comment: I took your comparable advice. Would you mind looking at my updated code and see what am missing now? I just want the contents to be sorted.  Currently it outputs the file path itself and the contents..but the contents are unsorted.

Comment: you are doing it all wrong.`InsertionSort(f);` in this line `f` is file name not the content of file. you should iterate over file and create a array and after all iteration pass this array to  `InsertionSort`

Comment: You have initialize a object of class `Word ` but not using it anywhere. DO you want to sort it?

Comment: If `Word` is the class you want to sort then Word class should implement Comparable interface